# Show that $\left\{ \omega \mid sup_{n}\{h_n(\omega)\} > c \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \omega \mid h_n (\omega) > c \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Given a sequence of measurable functions $h_n (\omega)$ I manged to prove that the sequence $inf_{n}\{h_n(\omega)\}$ is also measurable. For obtaining the same result for $sup_{n}\{h_n(x)\}$ I need to show that 
$$\left\{ \omega \mid sup_{n}\{h_n(\omega)\} > c \right\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \omega \mid h_n (\omega) > c \right\}$$

I managed to show that the left-hand set in contained in the right-hand set, however I cannot show the converse. Can someone give a detailed demonstration of the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega$ is in the union, then $h_{n_0}(\omega)>c$ for some $n_0$, hence $\sup_nh_n(\omega)\geq h_{n_0}(\omega)>c$. This shows that the right-hand side is contained in the left-hand side.

Comment: Why does the left inequality hold? The first part with supremum is in fact a sequence of real numbers for a fixed omega, the other is just a number. It might not hold, for example, if n > n_0

Comment: $\sup_nh_n(\omega)$ is just a number as well for $\omega$ fixed. To write it out fully, it is $\sup\{h_n(\omega):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Is it wrong to interpret it as $a_n = sup\{h_k(\omega)\mid k \geqslant n\}$ similar to the definition on wikipedia https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_superior_und_Limes_inferior

Comment: That's the lim sup, which is different from the supremum. The equality in your question is not true for the lim sup.

Comment: We get the lim sup only when we take the limit of the sequence $a_{n}$.  But I guess I should have understood $\sup_nh_n(\omega)$ the way you mentioned. Thank you.
It is just that I am unsure when to interpret such expressions as a sequence of supremums (like $a_{n}$) and when just as a number, i.e. a supremum of a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ \omega \in \{ t | \sup_n h_n(t) > c \} $ **iff** $\sup_n h_n(\omega) > c$ **iff** there exists some $n$ such that $h_n(\omega) > c$ **iff** there exists some $n$ such that $\omega \in \{ t | h_n(t) > c \}$ **iff** $\omega \in \cup_n \{ t | h_n(t) > c \}$